# Angular-Rails app Browser history navigating works not correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

My application is using RubyonRails and Angular. My problem is:
when im navigating pages manually - typing url`s and pressing 'Enter' (*rails routes working*) visiting for example **/welcome, /about, /home, /posts/98** and by pressing browser back and forward buttons can easily visit all these pages. 
Then when i click links of these pages (*angular routes working*) i can go back and forward in browser too. 
But if im visiting manually **/welcome** and then click **'about'**, **'home'** - from home i can get back to 'about' but pressing back from **'about'** page im getting **/welcome** page with empty **ng-view** div.

```
$rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
    console.log($window.history.state);  
});
```

By visiting page manually **$window.history.state** returns current url(same as **$location.absUrl();**).
By clicking links **$window.history.state** returns **null**.

I need to be able by clicking back or forward visit any route in **$window.history** regardless if page was visited manually(rails routes) or by clicking links(angular routes).
Will be glad to hear any ideas.

example of angular routes:

```
.when('/welcome', {templateUrl: '/angular_templates/welcome_process',controller: 'WelcomeController'})
.when('/about', {templateUrl: '/angular_templates/guidelines', controller: 'AboutCtrl'})
```

rails routes:

```
get 'welcome' => 'home#welcome_process',  as: :welcome
get 'about' => 'home#guidelines',  as: :guidelines
```

Answer (score -1):

Problem was solved by removing 'turbolinks' gem. (from Gemfile and made 'bundle clean --force').